# Windows Phone Application Analysis for Windows Phone 8 - Error starting

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Has anyone encountered this kind of error uring startup of this tool(from debug menu):

> "the type initializer for SIPShell.ProfilerContainer threw an
>   exception"

I cant use this tool now. I tried uninstalling resharper but it does not help. Some time ago this tool was working OK and now suddenly stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i managed to find an solution. One of VS extensions called BuildVision caused this issue. After disabling it everything is fine.